# Load raw image data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to do a bit of facebook integration with a website, and there's a particular call on the facebook api that post's a picture onto a users account. One of the parameters is the raw image data. The image is stored locally on the web server and I have a url to it. I was intending to load the image on the client using javascript until I learnt I couldn't do this. I'm currently trying an httpxml call to the server with the image url and intending for it to return the image data. This example code works with a url to a csv file, but it doesn't seem to want to read the image files contents. I'm getting an error when I try xmlhttp.responseText. The api call that I want to use this image data for is:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Photos.upload

```
function getFile(pURL,pFunc) {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); 
        if (xmlhttp) {
            eval('xmlhttp.onreadystatechange='+pFunc+';');
            xmlhttp.open('GET', pURL, false);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
}

function makeList() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) { 
        if (xmlhttp.status==200) { 
            var tmpArr=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById('theExample').innerHTML=tmpArr;
        }
    }
}
```

Please excuse my terrible understanding of this webby stuff. I need to learn it, but I also need to do this quick bit of work before I can sit down and learn all this good stuff. I've been entrenched in a C#/C++ world for too long.

Comment: Sorry this is kinda two questions in one. 
1. Why doesn't this work to get the contents of an image (not to display but to pass to facebook api)
2. Am I going in the right direction in order to do this API call.

I'll try out what's been suggested and see if I can get anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are writing a facebook app, using the facebook api, and trying to upload an image from your application to the users profile?

The api requires an HTTP post with mutli-part mime - think thats whats throwing you off.

Are you using a client library?  If so I assume you are using:http://facebook.codeplex.com/

This PHP reference has the basis that you need:  http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/using_the_facebook_api_to_upload_photos.php

One problem I see in your code is that you are trying to pull the image from a URL into responseText (a string) when you want responseBody (binary) instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(VS.85).aspx

Comment: responseBody isn't a standard property; for Firefox, you'll need to use a different trick, and for IE6, you're probably out of luck.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest

You're probably better off having the server make a backend HTTP request to submit the form post rather than trying to work around clientside differences.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the URL of the image on the server, why not just create an image element?

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = url; // assuming you have the URL in a variable called "url"
document.getElementById("image_holder").appendChild(img);
```